# How to generate 1000 symmetric matrices with defined letter?

Tags: matrix

I am just trying to create many number of random 3x3 matrices in the array (-100,100) for a statistical research and I am stuck to create symmetric many number of matrices. And also those matrices should be defined by letters, because after generation, all of those matrices place in an equation.

```
h[n_] := Module[{m}, m = RandomReal[{-100, 100}, {3, 3}];
m SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; i >= j -> 1, {3, 3}] + 
Transpose[m SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; i > j -> 1, {3, 3}]] // Normal]
h[3] // MatrixForm 
For[n = 0, n < 1000, n++, Print[h[n] // MatrixForm]]
```

with these code I can create 3x3 symmetric 1000 matrices, but how can I define these matrices as stable. I mean for example, for this code when I print h[7], everytime it gives another random matrix. How can I store those 1000 matrices for variables of h (h[n]) (I want stable matrices When I print any value of h[n]) ?

Comment: add `SeedRandom[1]; ` before `m = RandomReal[...];`

Comment: When I do that, every matrices give same solution for example h[1] and h[2] give the same matrix :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This creates 1000 symmetric random 3-by-3 matrices at once.

```
m = RandomReal[{-100, 100}, {1000, 3, 3}];
Do[m[[All, i, j]] = m[[All, j, i]], {i, 1, 3}, {j, i + 1, 3}];
```

You can reference the n-th matrix with `m[[n]]`. Note the double brackets as `m` is a three dimensional array. If you insist on single brackets then define

```
h[n_]:=m[[n]]
```

Comment: Thank you! Thats exactly what I want, I really appriciate that :)

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

```
letter = Alphabet[]

h[n_] := Module[{m}, SeedRandom[n]; m = RandomChoice[letter, {3, 3}];
                 m SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; i >= j -> 1, {3, 3}] + 
                 Transpose[m SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; i > j -> 1, {3, 3}]] // Normal]

h[3] // MatrixForm

For[n = 0, n < 1000, n++, Print[h[n] // MatrixForm]]
```

> {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z}
>
> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{p} & \text{i} & \text{v} \\
>  \text{i} & \text{b} & \text{o} \\
>  \text{v} & \text{o} & \text{s} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

... 1000 matrices ...

If you want different set use a different seed, for example, `SeedRandom[n+3]` or `SeedRandom[n+17]`.

Comment: You get me wrong I think I just want to create matrices for each value of matrices should be array of -100,100 but I Just define those matrices. with letter for example h[1] or h[2] or so on, I created this matrices but I cant store it with variables